# Open balls in $p$-adic numbers.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I am new to $p$-adic numbers and was watching an introductory [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdjYiU6skgE) about it. At 14:51, he says that $r$ only takes values in the form of $p^n$. However, I don't understand why $r$ must be restricted to numbers in the form of $p^n$. Given any r that is not in the form of $p^n$, there will be an integer $i$ such that $p^i<r<p^{i+1}$. Thus, the open ball set of $r$ would be the same as $p^{i+1}$﻿

Comment: That's the definition of $|.|_p$ : for $a= p^k b$ integer with $p \nmid b$ then $|a|_p = p^{-k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in any metric space, you **can** define an open ball of radius any real number.  But if the metric only takes values that are powers of $p$,  we **might as well** restrict attention to balls of radius a power of $p$.  I suspect that this was precisely the point the video was trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler example. In a discrete metric space $X$ where each $d(x,x)=0$ and $d(x,y)=1$ for $x \ne y$ it makes sense to talk about balls of any radius. However there are really only two types of balls at each point. Namely $B(x,r)=\{x\}$ for $r=0$ and $B(x,r)=X$ otherwise. So we don't lose anything if we decide to only consider balls of radius $0$ and $5$ say. Likewise for the adic numbers, every $B(x,r)$ is equal to some $B(x,p^n)$ so we don't lose anything by only talking about the latter set of balls.